# A question about the definition of $\overline{\nabla}_X \langle Y,Z\rangle$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections

Lee's "Riemannian Manifolds" has the following theorem:

> The Euclidean connection on $\Bbb{R}^n$ has one very nice property with respect to the Euclidean metric: it satisfies the product rule
>   $$\overline{\nabla}_X \langle Y,Z\rangle=\langle \overline{\nabla}_XY,Z\rangle + \langle Y,\overline{\nabla}_XZ\rangle$$

But $\langle Y,Z\rangle$ is not a vector field. How does $\overline{\nabla}_X \langle Y,Z\rangle$ make sense?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, $\langle Y, Z \rangle$ is a *scalar*, not a *vector*, field.  $\overline \nabla_X \langle Y, Z \rangle$ make sense by virtue of the fact that, for scalar fields $f$, we define

$\overline \nabla_X f = X[f] = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}, \tag 1$

where $t$ is a parameter along the integral curves of $X$:

$X = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}; \tag 2$

then the formula

$\overline \nabla_X \langle Y, Z \rangle = \langle \overline \nabla_X Y, Z \rangle + \langle Y, \overline \nabla_X Z \rangle \tag 3$

expresses

$\overline \nabla_X \langle Y, Z \rangle = X[\langle Y, Z \rangle] \tag 4$

as the sum of the two inner products $\langle \overline \nabla_X Y, Z \rangle$ and $\langle Y, \overline \nabla _X Z \rangle$.

This is all of course just a generalization of the well-known formula in Euclidean spaces:

$\dfrac{d}{dt} (\vec v(t) \cdot \vec y(t)) = \dot {\vec v}(t) \cdot \vec y(t) + \vec v(t) \cdot \dot {\vec y}(t), \tag 5$

where $t$ is the parameter along some curve on which $\vec v(t)$, $\vec y(t)$ are defined.

Comment: This is exactly right. See Lemma 4.6(b) in my book for the definition of covariant derivatives of scalar functions (i.e., $0$-tensor fields).

Comment: @JackLee:  is your book available online?  and thanks for the kind words!

Comment: The only online version currently available (legally, anyway) is a PDF e-book that can be [purchased from Springer](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387982717). But I would advise against buying it right now, because the much-improved [second edition](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783319917542) should be available within a month or two. If you're connected with a university that has a subscription to Springer's GTM series, you'll be able to read the second edition online for free.

Comment: @JackLee:  OK, thanks.  I may be able to access it through my university.